# How can i add edges in graph (beginner)

Tags: python, graph

i want to add edge to current graph
Here is my code for the graph

```
def mGraph():
    graph = {'A': {'B': 1, 'C': 2},
             'B': {'C': 2, 'D': 1},
             'C': {'D': 1},
             'D': {'C': 2},
             'E': {'F': 1},
             'F': {'C': 2}}
    return graph
```

and here is the add edges function

```
def add_edge(graph, aa1, aa2):
         graph[aa1].update()[aa2]
         graph[aa2].update()[aa1]
         return graph
```

i ask the user input first node and second node

```
def main():
    graph = mGraph()
    option = ''
    while option != 'terminate':
        print(" a. Display")
        print(" c. Add Edges")
        option = input("Enter your option:")

        if option == "a":
            print(graph)

        if option == "c":
            a1 = input("First Edge")
            a2 = input("Second Edge")
            print(add_edge(graph, a1, a2))


main()
```

i want to link two edges to current graph and want to modify them. if user enter A in "First Edge" and D in "Second Edge". i want see changes in the graph. user input should reflect on the graph.

i got error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:......", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:......", line 49, in main
    print(add_edge(graph, a1, a2))
  File "C:......", line 25, in add_edge
    graph[aa1].update()[aa2]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: what output do you expected ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `[aa2]` in `graph[aa1].update()[aa2]`? It is  useless and incorrect, because `update` always returns `None`.

Comment: If user enter A in first node and D in second node i expected 'A': {'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 1}, and 'D': {'C': 2, 'A' : 1}. @BhargavDesai

Comment: You have to learn how the function `update` works.  Read its documentation, have a look at a tutorial. Programmers learn by reading and doing.

Comment: what function can i use to add edges to current graph sir if update cannot use in this function @DYZ

Comment: You use the right function, but you do not use it right. Learn how to use it. Why do I have to say it twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
def add_edge(graph, aa1, aa2):
         first_value = graph[aa1].copy()
         for k,v in first_value.items():
            if aa2 in k:
                graph[aa1].update({aa2:v+1})
                break
            else:
                graph[aa1].update({aa2:1})
         second_value = graph[aa2].copy()
         for k,v in second_value.items():
            if aa1 in k:
                graph[aa2].update({aa1:v+1})
                break
            else:
                graph[aa2].update({aa1:1})
         return graph
```